# Placing a WMS layer above a WFS layer makes WFS layer not selectable

Tags: wms, wfs, layers, openlayers-2

I have two different layers which I call from Geoserver. The first one is a WMS layer with points and the second one is WFS layer with lines. 
I need to display the points above the lines and I also need to be able to select each line and get some data.
I use the Openlayers2 library to display the layers on the map.
I set the index of the WMS layer like this:

```
wms_layer.setZIndex( 1001 );
```

So I am sure it will appear on top when I display it from the layer switcher.
But the problem is that when I make visible the WMS layer then the WFS layer is not clickable.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afterall I decided to use a WFS layer instead of a WMS one. I still had the same problem but it was fixed when I added the layer in the following code:

```
clickControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
                    [wfs_layer_network,wfs_layer_komvoi,wfs_layer_freatia], // wfs_layer_freatia -> added layer
                    {
                        clickout: true,
                        //hover: true,
                        //box: true
                    }
    );
```